# Scrolling only selected content in the body document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to use the page scroll effect so that only the content of the #right element is scrolled in the layout. A similar effect can be seen on Facebook when scrolling posts (posts are scrolled while the left panel and upper bar remain in place). Any of you have an idea how can I get the same effect for my #right container in the code?

```css
#header,#footer{
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  background:blue;
}

#content{
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#left{
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  background:green;
  margin:20px 0;
  height:100vh;
}

#right{
  float:right;
  width:calc(100% - 220px);
}

.item{
  height:80px;
  margin:20px 0;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    header
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="right"> 
    <!-- this content is scrolling-->
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using JQuery you can add a class with style of `position:fixed` and `top:0` and triggered using scroll function for better view/effect of the element on the side.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var header_height = $('#header').height();
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > header_height) {
          $('#left').addClass('fixed');
      } else {
          $('#left').removeClass('fixed');
      }
});
```

```css
#header,#footer{
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  background:blue;
}

#content{
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#left{
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  background:green;
  margin:20px 0;
  height:100vh;
}

#right{
  float:right;
  width:calc(100% - 220px);
}

.item{
  height:80px;
  margin:20px 0;
  background:red;
}

.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
    header
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="right"> 
    <!-- this content is scrolling-->
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

Comment: It meets my requirements. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: fixed` property in **CSS**

```css
#header,#footer{
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  background:blue;
}

#content{
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#left{
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  background:green;
  /* Enter The Position Fixed Property Here! */
  position:fixed;
  margin:20px 0;
  height:100vh;
}

#right{
  float:right;
  width:calc(100% - 220px);
}

.item{
  height:80px;
  margin:20px 0;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    header
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="right"> 
    <!-- this content is scrolling-->
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

There is some position disblancing because you have your header. Use this property to which div you want to stick with scroll. An do placement as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use position: fixed and decrease its height of class "left".